# Why does my code not run in Unity? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

For some reason, my code is not working... I have no idea why. can someone help? I am using a switch statement to control my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        string state = "idle";
        float vx = 0f;
        float vy = 0f;
        float playerSpeed = 2f * Time.deltaTime;

        switch (state) {
            case "idle": 
                vx = 0;
                vy = 0;

                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) state = "left";
                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) state = "right";
                if (!Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) state = "idle";             
                break;

            case "left":
                vx = -1 * playerSpeed;
                vy = 0;

                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) state = "left";
                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) state = "right";
                if (!Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) state = "idle";             
                break;

            case "right":
                vx = playerSpeed;
                vy = 0;

                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) state = "left";
                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) state = "right";
                if (!Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) state = "idle";             
                break;
        }
        vx += pos.x;
        vy += pos.y;
        pos += transform.position;

    }
}
```

The console has no errors, and I can not see any error with my code...

Please help!

any answers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Any error? Exceptions? Unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're evaluating your input in each switch case instead of before you evaluate the switch. You're also checking input and then the lack of it so just use `else` to clean up those checks.  You're also doing nothing other than `vy = 0` so don't bother setting that:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
    state = "left";
else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) // if you hold both A and D, A will get priority
    state = "right";
else
    state = "idle";
switch(state)
{
    case("idle")
        vx = 0;
        break;
    case("left")
        vx = playerSpeed;
        break;
    case("right")
        vx = -1 * playerSpeed;
        break;
}
```

You're also not adding the values to the position of the transform properly, you're just adding them to your temporary variable, `pos` (a variable you don't need at all):

```
vx += pos.x;
vy += pos.y;
pos += transform.position;
```

should instead be:

```
transform.position.Translate(vx, vy, 0);
```

---

I'd also like to point out that the switch itself is entirely pointless but I made this my answer so it's clear what's being done wrong; you should just be setting your `vx` values in the `if`/`else if`/`else` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You see, I feel like the "state" is getting reset to "Idle" everytime. can you try moving that `string state = "idle";` Start() function 
then add this `state = "idle";` somewhere else like at the buttom of

```
   vx += pos.x;
   vy += pos.y;
   pos += transform.position;
```

You see you have a Switch Case. which will pass the code once, you see those breaks? thats why they don't enter or receive the values change on your vx and vy. I suggest you just use If Else instead of a switch for detecting the input.